# flutter iOS app is stuck on launchscreen when installed on real device

Tags: ios, flutter

I have this flutter app where I've set up a flutter_native_splash screen with the package that is named the same.
I've used the command and the description from the installation guide (pub spec.yaml etc.) and my app runs fine when tested on android emulator, real android device and debug mode in iOS simulator (and on real device).
Now the confusing thing is, that the app is getting sometimes in the splash screen where the app is opened. This only happens when I'm installing the version from TestFlight.
But when I'm trying to open up the app multiple times, it opens the app to the home screen. No error is shown in the console and so on, my flutter doctor is saying that everything is installed correctly.

Here is my main.dart code:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  //Notifications
  await FirebaseApi().initNotifications();
  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
  //Hive Database
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  //Analytics init
  FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;
  final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
      await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  runApp(const AulingerMain());
  // Need await here
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1));
  FlutterNativeSplash.remove();
}

class AulingerMain extends StatefulWidget {
  const AulingerMain({super.key});

  @override
  State<AulingerMain> createState() => _AulingerMainState();
}

class _AulingerMainState extends State<AulingerMain> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OverlaySupport(
      child: MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ListenableProvider<UserProvider>(create: (_) => UserProvider()),
        ],
        child: ThemeModeHandler(
            manager: ThemeManager(),
            builder: (ThemeMode themeMode) {
              return MaterialApp(
                  title: 'Gasthof zum Sonnenwald',
                  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                  theme: ThemeData(
                      appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
                    centerTitle: true,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
                  )),
                  darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
                  themeMode: themeMode,
                  home: FutureBuilder<bool>(
                    future: checkFirstTime(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return const Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.amber),
                        );
                      }

                      final isFirstTime = snapshot.data ?? true;

                      return isFirstTime
                          ? const EinfuehrungFrage()
                          : const AutoLoginHandler();
                    },
                  ), //sets home to autologinhandler at start for auto login
                  builder: (context, child) {
                    return MediaQuery(
                      data:
                          MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
                      child: child!,
                    );
                  },
                  routes: {
                    Settings.routeName: (ctx) => const Settings(),
                    MainPage.routeName: (ctx) => const MainPage(),
                    Speisekarte.routeName: (ctx) => const Speisekarte(),
                    ContactUsPage.routeName: (ctx) => const ContactUsPage(),
                    LoginScreen.routeName: (ctx) => const LoginScreen(),
                    ImprintScreen.routeName: (ctx) => const ImprintScreen(),
                    SelectionScreenEssen.routeName: (ctx) =>
                        const SelectionScreenEssen(),
                    PrivacyPolicyScreen.routeName: (ctx) =>
                        const PrivacyPolicyScreen(),
                  });
            }),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> checkFirstTime() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool isFirstTime = prefs.getBool('isFirstTime') ?? true;
    return isFirstTime;
  }
}

class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}
```

This is the code from pubsped.yaml:

```
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#FFFFFF"
  image: assets/icons/appstore.png
  image_dark: assets/icons/appstore.png
  color_dark: "#282828"
  android: true
  ios: true
```

I hope you can help me with this one! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `FlutterNativeSplash.remove();` too early. You should call that line in the `initState()` method of your first screen.

```dart
class _AulingerMainState extends State<AulingerMain> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    FlutterNativeSplash.remove();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
```

EDIT:
In your main method, replace

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

with

```
WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help. Sadly, the error is not fixed. It still hangs on the splash-screen sometimes. I really don't know what to do.

Comment: I've edited my answer, try the new solution to see if it works.

Comment: Hey Eric! Sadly, your answer produces the same issue again. I've updated all the packages from pub.dev to the newest Version (firebase etc.) but that doesn't change anything. Idk any further...